# Helm: Extra newline when using "include" for templating

Tags: go, kubernetes, yaml, kubernetes-helm

I get a weird new line when my chart is rendered that templates from another file using `{{ include }}`. For instance, my manifest looks like this

```
      containers:
      - name: {{ .Release.Name }}
        image: {{ .Values.global.image}}:{{ .Values.global.imageTag }}
        imagePullPolicy: {{ .Values.global.pullPolicy }}
        ports:
          - containerPort: {{ .Values.gloabl.containerPort }}
{{ include "common_deployment" . }}
```

and my `common_deployment` is defined as

```
{{- define "common_deployment" }}
        envFrom:
          - secretRef:
              name: {{ .Release.Name }}-secret
{{- end -}}
```

when I look at my manifest after doing a dry run on Helm, my template looks something like this

```
 containers:
  - name: test
    image: myrepo/myimage:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    ports:
      - containerPort: 4444

envFrom:
  - secretRef:
      name: test-secret
```

Notice how there is a new lie between the `ports` and the `envFrom`. I'm wondering if this will affect how my pods will turn out because there are issues with volumes being mounted and I want to be able to make sure that this templating problem is the culprit before going down another rabbit hole.

Comment: Try to insert dash sign into the include clause

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use a hyphen to suppress the newline on template commands. You're already using it for `define` and `end`.

Similarly, you should use `{{- include ... -}}`.

Answer (score 13):

There's one thing to consider when you use the `include` function with the [`indent`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#indent) function, to indent the template, like so:

```sh
{{- include "common_deployment" . | indent 4 }}
```

The above command also indents the leading newline introduced by `include` by 4 spaces, so the resulting output will be as follows (spaces indicated as `$`):

```
    ports:
      - containerPort: 4444$$$$\n
$$$$envFrom:
$$$$  - secretRef:
$$$$      name: test-secret
```

This doesn't break the YAML syntax, as whitespaces are ignored anyway, but it may be reported, e.g. in `diff` outputs.

To prevent this, you can trim the leading newline generated by `include` with the [`trim`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#trim) function, and use the [`nindent`](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#nindent) function, like so:

```
{{- include "common_deployment" . | trim | nindent 4 }}
```

Now, only the actual lines of the template are indented, and the newline is inserted by the `nindent` function:

```
    ports:
      - containerPort: 4444\n
$$$$envFrom:
$$$$  - secretRef:
$$$$      name: test-secret
```

Comment: Brilliant, this is what helped in my case. It seems like supplying dashes `{{- ... -}}` is not enough for `nindent` indeed.